# Verify if I receive a date before applying a filter in ionic v3

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm working with ionic v3.
Specifically: Ionic@3.20.1

I have the following code fragment

```
<button 
  ion-item
  *ngFor="let case of cases"
  (click)="show($event, case)">
  <h3>
    {{case.date | date: 'H:mm'}}
  </h3>
</button>
```

I want to verify that the value of `case.date` is of type **date** to avoid InvalidPipeArgument.

Any idea to do it with the use of `ngIf`? I want to avoid using methods.

Thanks

Comment: so, what do you expect to happen if a `case` instance has a non-date `date` property? should the button for it not be rendered? should a placeholder by put in place?

Comment: If case.date is not a date, I would like it to show nothing. The code that is presented is an example, only to demonstrate the use of the filter date: 'H:mm'. Thanks